# Magento2 product export based on website?

Tags: magento2, product, export

I have 20+ website in my Magento store. If I click `System->Data Transfer ->Export` if I click the export means all website products are exporting.

But, I want to export product based on the website, I need to add the filter for that, please tell me how to create that website filter attribute in magento backend or else I need to write any custom script for that attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There, I wrote full article on this question.

I believe you will find this link useful

https://marjan7790.wordpress.com/2018/09/18/add-website-filter-to-product-export/

Comment: You are welcome...

Comment: The Github link is redirecting to a 404 page